# neod3.js usage to visualize neo4j data on a seperate website

Tags: neo4j, visualization

Im trying to use the standard neo4j visualisation in a seperate Website (not the original Neo4j Webbrowser). Therefore I downloaded the library from here:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/master/community/browser/lib/visualization

I really struggle with using it. I actually have no real idea. I tried including it into a html file but hardly failed.

Did anyone do this? Would be very nice, if someone could help me out.

Thanks a lot!

Greetings
Schakron

Comment: You can check how the graphgist project uses it: http://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist the library is called neod3 or my cy2neo has a branch that uses neod3 https://github.com/jexp/cy2neo/tree/neod3/scripts

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at it. :)

Comment: Hey Michael,
If I use your cy2neo on my database, I get different results than from my original neo4j WebInterface. Do you know whats the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Those are all coffee files (coffeescript, which compiles into javascript).  It looks like if you go up two levels there's a README which shows you how to start it up using npm and grunt:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/master/community/browser

The app itself (maybe it's a node.js app, though I don't see references to node) is under the `app` directory from there.  It has `jade` files which would be the HTML views (jade compiles to HTML similar to how coffescript compiles to javascript).

So presumably if you get that all set up there will be a server serving up HTML which will compile and serve up those coffeescript files as javascript in the page